# Remap inferior-python-mode C-z key to python quit rather than emacs suspend or undo

Tags: python, emacs, python-mode

So here's a technical question on how to exit from the current job of the inferior-python interpreter.

Normally, C-z does the trick if I run the interpreter in a regular command shell.  This calls python exit and whatever is running stops. The interpreter process is still alive.

However, in emacs when I press C-z in the inferior shell it runs the undo command ( I use CUA-mode). If I disable CUA it will run the suspend-emacs command. What I want is to either unbind C-z completely or remap C-z to actually send an break signal to python just like it would do in a regular shell.
I tried these brutal ways:
(global-unset-key "\C-z")
(global-unset-key [?\C-z])

None of them seem to work and C-z is still stuck as undo or suspend/inconify emacs.

I also tried regular signals:
The only signal that I can send to the inferior shell is QUIT  which is undesirable since that effectively kills the interpreter and its process(C-c C-). The signal STOP does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When running an inferior process, you generally can send control sequences with the <kbd>C-c</kbd> prefix.  With that in mind, try

```
C-c C-z
```

Which, for me, is bound to [`comint-stop-subjob`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Shell-Mode.html).

Comment: C-c C-z doesn't do it  for me but I realized C-c C-c breaks the job and keeps the interpreter alive. The reason I wasn't seeing this before was that I was running C/C++ modules using the python bindings and the "break" could not occur immediately; it had to wait until one C++ module finished executing